# JBDC : retrieve a list of object after a query

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to write a simple jdbc program to interact with my embeded H2 database. The query that I try to do is the following :

```
 "SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE NAME=TEST"
```

The problem here is that many objects can have the same name (only the ID is unique). And I don't know how can I retrieve all the objects of my database that have the same name.
So far, I write this program :

```
public Milestone findByName(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Milestone milestone = new Milestone();

    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/dao_db", "sa", "");
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE NAME=?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);

    System.out.println("Milestone selected with name = "+  name);

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    if(resultSet.next())
       {
         milestone.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
         milestone.setName(name);
         milestone.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
        }

    connection.close();

    return milestone;
}
```

The problem is that this code only returns one element (with the first ID) and ignore the other objects in my database that have the same name.

Can you help me please to deal with this problem? I'm not very familiar with the list concepts in Java. Thanks

Comment: Well, basically you just need to loop through the result set (`while(resultSet.next()`)
 and store the data into a `List<Milestone>` within the loop. The [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) gives you this info (and more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition should be a while:

```
try{
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MILESTONE WHERE NAME=?");
    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);

    System.out.println("Milestone selected with name = "+  name);
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    List<Milestone> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(resultSet.next(){
         Milestone milestone= new Milestone();
         milestone.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
         milestone.setName(name);
         milestone.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
         list.add(milestone);
    }
}
finally{
    if(connection != null){
        try{
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return list;
```